# Update statement Fails in VBA code when the MS Access Database is Closed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following update statement in my VBA program.

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "UPDATE SourceTicketData SET PRESENT = 'Checked-In' where CONTROLNUM = " & ticketno & ""
```

However, this statement executes without any problem when my MS Access Database is Open.

When I close the database, the update statement gives:

> error code 91 object variable or with block variable not set.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: `Set db = CurrentDb` implies the current database that you are in or that is open. So, if you are really writing this in Excel VBA, use `ADO` or `DAO` to connect to and query the db

Comment: I used DAO but it is not working. Below is my updated code                              
    Dim res3 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String                                                                                       
    With res3
            
                .Fields("PRESENT") = "Checked-In"
                .Update
                .Close
            End With
            
            Set res3 = Nothing

Comment: To be honest, the code in your comment is so far off, I suggest you read a tutorial on how to connect to database via DAO and then subsequently update a record in a table. Then if you get stuck, draft a new question with a [mcve] on what your issue is.